# How to timeout when calling an API asynchronously?

Tags: asynchronous, dart, flutter, timeout

I am calling an API using async and await and want to navigate to next screen after the api call is over.
I am not using async loader or futurebuilder coz I don't want to show any new widget till I get the response of the api call.
I am able to call the API, show the circular progress indicator until I get response but I don't know how to execute time out of the api.
I am not using Future.delayed for timeout coz I want the api to be called immediately.

Comment: How do I handle the case when net is off and SocketException oocurs?

Comment: Remi Rousselet, I tried using your answer to the question - final result = await Future.value(42).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 3));  I am trying  to test the case by switching off net, how do I add timeout for Socket Exception case? Is there a way to keep trying for a period of time? Say user turns on net at 30th sec, API should get hit automatically.